# removeEventListener from another array-prototype forEach

Tags: foreach, removeeventlistener

**Hello, friends!**

I'm new to Javascript. Using native JS.

I need when I click on the red button the blue button becomes disabled using removeEventListener. And vice versa - clicking on the blue button will add removeEventListener to the red button.
But my method does not work because the first array does not see the other array.
Thanks for the help. And, please, add comments to your code))

Here is the code and example https://jsfiddle.net/of83ycmx/

```
<body>
<button class="red">Red</button>
<button class="blue">Blue</button>
<div class="box">BOX</div>

<button class="red">Red</button>
<button class="blue">Blue</button>
<div class="box">BOX</div>

<script>
    const box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
    const red = document.querySelectorAll('.red');
    const blue = document.querySelectorAll('.blue');

    red.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', function redListener() {
            box[i].classList.add('redBox');
            //removeEventListener doesnt work because blueListener is not defined
            //item.removeEventListener('click', blueListener);
        });
    });

    blue.forEach((item, i) => {
        item.addEventListener('click', function blueListener() {

            box[i].classList.add('blueBox');
            //  item.removeEventListener('click', redListener)

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

made some changes that made sense to me. I am quite a beginner, so anyone who sees anything no-no or bad practice go ahead and call me out.

### What should happen:

---

**My interpretation of your explanation is this:** When a user clicks on 1 of 2 buttons, the button that was NOT clicked should have its event listener removed.

### Solution:

---

**Making the functions accessible was your main problem**-named functions inside of event listeners are limited to that listener (I assume). So instead move the function outside of the listener and simply call the function:

```
function blueListener () {
    // Do stuff here
}

item.addEventListener('click', blueListener)
```

Now the function is accessible to the other function, so when you remove the event listener you wont get `blueListener is not defined`.

By wrapping the buttons and the box in a div allows you to select the button you need. Using `.querySelectorAll()` on the parent div allows you to select the button with the respective class (i. e the selecting the blue button when you click the red button).

The functions don't need any other info; they use `this` to access the clicked element. Then you can find the parent element, and select the box to change the background color, and select the respective button to remove the event listener.

### DEMO:

---

```js
const box = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
const red = document.querySelectorAll('.red');
const blue = document.querySelectorAll('.blue');

function redListener() {
  var parent = this.parentElement;
  var box = parent.querySelectorAll('.box')[0]
  var blueButton = parent.querySelectorAll('.blue')[0]
  
  box.classList.add('redBox');
  blueButton.removeEventListener('click', blueListener)
}

function blueListener() {
  var parent = this.parentElement;
  var box = parent.querySelectorAll('.box')[0]
  var redButton = parent.querySelectorAll('.red')[0]
  
  box.classList.add('blueBox');
  redButton.removeEventListener('click', redListener)
}

red.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', redListener)
})

blue.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.addEventListener('click', blueListener)
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Segoe UI,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,Apple Color Emoji,Segoe UI Emoji;
}
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(172, 172, 172);
  margin: 0px 0px 40px 0px;
  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.redBox {
  background-color: rgb(156, 56, 56);
}

.blueBox {
  background-color: rgb(66, 56, 156);
}
```

```html
 <div class="buttons">
   <button class="red">Red</button>
   <button class="blue">Blue</button>
   <div class="box">BOX</div>
 </div>



 <div class="buttons">
   <button class="red">Red</button>
   <button class="blue">Blue</button>
   <div class="box">BOX</div>
 </div>
```